# Textfill for jQuery 1.6? (not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you can enlighten me. I'm trying to use GeekMonkey's textfill plugin in a joomla website which has jQuery 1.6.1 (the template uses it). The plugin is not working. Is there any way to fix this? I can't find any other textfill out there!

This is GeekMonkey's plugin:

```
; (function($) {
    /**
    * Resizes an inner element's font so that the inner element completely fills the outer element.
    * @author Russ Painter WebDesign@GeekyMonkey.com
    * @version 0.1
    * @param {Object} Options which are maxFontPixels (default=40), innerTag (default='span')
    * @return All outer elements processed
    * @example <div class='mybigdiv filltext'><span>My Text To Resize</span></div>
    */
    $.fn.textfill = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            maxFontPixels: 40,
            innerTag: 'span'
        };
        var Opts = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var fontSize = Opts.maxFontPixels;
            var ourText = $(Opts.innerTag + ':visible:first', this);
            var maxHeight = $(this).height();
            var maxWidth = $(this).width();
            var textHeight;
            var textWidth;
            do {
                ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
                textHeight = ourText.height();
                textWidth = ourText.width();
                fontSize = fontSize - 1;
            } while ((textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth) && fontSize > 3);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jtextfill').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 36, innerTag: 'h1' });
});
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.jtextfill').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 70 });

            $('#dyntext').keyup(function() {
                $('.dyntextval').html(this.value);
                $('.jtextfill').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 70 });
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance,
desperate user.-

Answer (score 0):

For that plugin to work you need to

- set the container's (`.jtextfill`) width and height
- display the inner tag inline (`display:inline` in the CSS).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2btyN/