# jQuery textFill does not work on invisible elements

Tags: jquery

I try to adapt the size of a text within a `div`, which in turn is inside another. In general and in a simplified way, I have the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main:{
  display:none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.square-text:{
  width:100%;
  height: 120px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#main").append("<div class='square-text' ><h3>...text here...</h3></div>");
$(".square-text").textFill({changeLineHeight: true, innerTag: 'h3', maxFontPixels: 0});
```

However, when `div` # main is displayed on the screen, `textFill` has not produced any effect, instead it is on screen from the beginning if it works.

I will greatly appreciate how to solve this! =)

```js
$("#main, #main_other").append("<div class='text'><h3>Text Here</h3></div>");

$('.text').textfill({changeLineHeight: true, innerTag: 'h3', maxFontPixels: 0});

setTimeout(function(){
  $("#main").css({"display":"inline"});
}, 5000);
```

```css
#main{
  display: none;
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}

#main_other{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}

.text{
  background:red;
  width:80%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://jquery-textfill.github.io/js/textfill/jquery.textfill.js"></script>



<div id="main">

</div>

<div id="main_other">

</div>
```

Comment: `textFil()` is some sort of plugin, not part of jQuery core . Without link to docs for it probability of anyone really knowing what it does or it's internal workings is likely low. A [mcve] would help also

Comment: maxfontpixels 0 looks suspicious. what does the documentation say? could you make a jsfiddle from this so we could test? [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7079838/1132334), which version do you use?

Comment: From the [textFill documentation](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill): *innerTag*: The child element tag to resize. We select it by using `$(innerTag + ':visible:first', container)`.  Since the `h3` is not visible, using `innerTag` will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the css as:

```
#main:{
  visibility:hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

This should solve your problem.